Help interpreting GLM interaction effect (Poisson with offset)
I've modelled a count variable using a Poisson glm and an offset variable. I'm looking at the effect of sampled year on the number of times people who are 'old' ( > age x) perform a behaviour compared to younger individuals (< age x). The offset variable is the ln(observation time). I've included an interaction term as I'm expecting that individuals in the older category are experiencing more severe biological ageing than those in the younger category, and therefore should exhibit a more severe relationship over the years. This seems to be the case with my model output:
Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      -0.57004    0.10661  -5.347 8.96e-08 ***
Year_Scaled      -0.12309    0.07831  -1.572   0.1160    
OldY             -0.19841    0.14128  -1.404   0.1602    
Year_Scaled:OldY -0.21954    0.09609  -2.285   0.0223 *  

I want to estimate the effect size of the interaction on the rate ratio over time. But how do I do this? So far I have constructed the following equation to estimate the rate ratio for 'old' individuals over each year:
exp(Intercept + YEAR*(Year_Scaled:OldY)) = Rate ratio of that year
What I'm not sure about is if I need to include the non-significant terms in this equation? I'm aware my interaction term's significance is relative to the slope of younger individuals, so do I need to adapt my equation to account for this slope? E.g.
exp(Intercept + YEAR*(Year_Scaled + Year_Scaled:OldY)) = Rate ratio of that year
Equally, do i then also need to account for the intercept of the old group, even though it was not significant?
exp(Intercept + OLDY + YEAR*(Year_Scaled + Year_Scaled:OldY)) = Rate ratio of that year.
I think I'm overthinking this, but I could use some advice!

If you exclude non-significant terms, you are pretending they have an estimate of $\hat{\beta}_j = 0$. This isn't what your model estimated. Also, why are you using a minus sign for some estimates?

So I should include all terms for the model, such as:
exp(Intercept + OLDY + YEAR*(Year_Scaled + Year_Scaled:OldY))

Also, apologies, i used - signs because the coefficients were negatives - I will edit this in the main question

The scaling complicates things slightly, you can't just do Year * [estimate of scale(Year)] because a unit increase in year is not the same as a unit increase in the scaled year variable. Try running attr(scale(Year), "scaled:scale") to see what Year was divided by in the scaling.

Ah yes thats what I've done - I just wanted to make it clear it was different to the slope coefficient in the example. :-) Would you therefore suggest using the formula in the comment above to calculate the rate ratio?

If you were to exclude non-significant terms, you are pretending they have an estimate of $\hat{\beta}_j=0$. This is not what your model estimated. Hence, you should include all relevant estimates. Whether they are significant or not has nothing to do with it.
A second complication arises from scaling. This can be taken into account as follows (example data at the bottom of this post):
GLM <- glm(y ~ Year_Scaled * Old, family = "poisson", data = DF)
betahat <- coef(GLM)

a <- attr(scale(Year), "scaled:center")
b <- attr(scale(Year), "scaled:scale")

# Example 1: Young, 1992
exp(betahat[1] + betahat[2] * (1992 - a) / b)
# 0.4620108

# Example 2: Old, 1964
exp(betahat[1] + (betahat[2] + betahat[4]) * (1964 - a) / b + betahat[3])
# 0.2552082

An easier way to do this in R, is by using the scale function within the formula of the GLM. This then allows you to use predict as you would normally, filling in the unscaled year:
GLM_scaled <- glm(y ~ scale(Year) * Old, family = "poisson", data = DF)
predict(GLM_scaled, newdata = data.frame(Year = 1992, Old = "N"), type = "response")
# 0.4620108
predict(GLM_scaled, newdata = data.frame(Year = 1964, Old = "Y"), type = "response")
# 0.2552082 


Example data:
set.seed(2024)
Year <- rep(-10000:2024, 2)
Year_Scaled <- scale(Year)
Old  <- factor(rep(c("Y", "N"), each = length(Year) / 2), levels = c("N", "Y"))
X <- model.matrix(~ Year_Scaled * Old)
beta <- c(-0.57004, -0.12309, -0.19841, -0.21954)
eta <- X %*% beta
n <- length(eta)
y <- rpois(n, exp(eta))
DF <- data.frame(y, Year, Year_Scaled, Old)


Thank you very much :-) That helps a lot

@ElliotHoward-Spink You're welcome! If this answered your question you can click the check mark to accept it.
